# How do I tell Closure Compiler to include all source files from a given directory only for modules?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

---

I have a directory of scripts:

```
/scripts/module-foo.js
/scripts/module-bar.js
/scripts/site.js
/scripts/some_other_non_module_script.js
```

the two `module` scripts export modules:

```
goog.module('foo');

exports = 'foo';
```

And the `site.js` script includes them:

```
var foo = goog.module.get('foo');
```

I can get this to work fine if I manually specify each source file in the compiler command:

```
java -jar compiler.jar ... --js module-foo.js --js module-bar.js --js site.js
```

but I'm trying to avoid that.  If I specify

```
--js ./**
```

It works, but I get the source from `site.js` as well as `some_other_non_module_script.js` in the same output file.  I only want `site.js`

Answer (score 0):

`site.js` will need to have a `goog.provide` statement itself - something like `goog.provide('mysite')`. Then you can use the `--only_closure_dependencies` and `--closure_entry_point` flags.

```
java -jar compiler.jar ... --js scripts/**.js --only_closure_dependencies
  --closure_entry_point mysite
```

[Learn about the Manage Closure Dependencies Flags](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Manage-Closure-Dependencies)

Comment: Thanks, that's one possibility, but it still requires a different build script per file being built, which is what I don't want.  I just want to pass the file name.  Do you know if it's possible to do this with in-file flags?

Comment: You could name could make your `goog.provide` entry point name be the file name. But other than that, the compiler doesn't have built-in support for what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: For now I renamed a bunch of files to `module-...js` so I can add scripts like `--js **/module-*.js`.  I might add a quick shell-script regex to pull out an entry point, but I'm not sure yet if I want to do that.  Meh.